# Ubuntu freezing randomly 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, crash

I have just installed ubuntu on my computer and every time I turn on a program that's ubuntu related like terminal for example after around 1min of the program being on it crashes and onLy holding down the power button will turn it off.Also it used to say there was a software problem now it doesn't it could not have Time to report it before it crashed.Can any one help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: It says command not found

Comment: Please do not retype the command but copy it and paste to terminal. You made some typos, e.g. the first symbol is not a number ;-)

Comment: Cant connect to the Internet cause of glitch but I cant fix the glitch in time before it crashes

Comment: So type it more careful. The first letter is `l` like in lemon.

Comment: When I type it more carefully and check it when I press enter it does nothing

Comment: That is not possible. What video adapter do you have there?

Comment: Very old its a Nvidia quadro fx 1400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by installing an Nvidia driver. Connect to internet and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304
```

Comment: Thats one problem I cant connect to the internet

Comment: It is not clear why you can't. You can get to console by Ctrl+Alt+F1, connect from there and install the driver.

Comment: Its a WiFi adapter I installed but the its glitch cede so I need to fix it but I cant Figure out how to do it here's a form i found on how to fix the WiFi problem http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-trusty-realtek.html

Comment: I suggest connecting by wire, then fix the video driver issue. After that you can fix the wireless.

Comment: I dont have either net maybe I can move it temp.

Comment: Cant move i would have to move it down 3 flights of star IRS any other ways in can fix it?